# Maximum Diversity: translate an heuristic algorithm in C (or pseudocode)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics

I have a set of N items and I know their mutual distances. every element has a cost and I have a budget. I should accomplish the following task: suppose I put an Item in the basket, the following item in the basket will be the item whose distance is the maximum from the first (under budget constraint) the third item will be the item whose sum of distances from item1 and item2 is the maximum (under budget constraints), a forth item will be the one whose sum of distances from item 1,2 and 3 is the maximum (always budget) etc. How do I find the subset whose total distance (computed as above) is max? Do you know any algorithm to solve this problem? thanks in advance

UPDATE: I've done some research and this problem is called Maximum Diversity Problem. I can't traslate the heuristic algorithm (that would solve the problem) stated above in C or pseudocode!

Comment: This sounds like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and can probably be [solved similarly](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/knapsack-problem/)

Comment: @xtratic thanks for your answer! It's not a knapsack problem since the order in which I put items in the basket matters.

Comment: Does the 2nd item *have* to be the most distant (given it fulfills the budget constraint) or can it be a little nearer if this choice will allow a bigger overall distance in the end?

Comment: @PatriceGahide it has to be the most distant! than the third has to be the one that has the biggest the sum of distances between the two before and so on.. Thanks!

Comment: This problem is known as Maximum Diversity Problem and the algorithm stated above would solve it!

Comment: This doesn't look like an instance of the MDP because here, once you choose a starting item, computing the result is mechanical (considering your answer to my previous question). You have no notion of order in the MDP.

Comment: @PatriceGahide From what I read I understood that the algorithm above when iterated over all possible starting element is a simple Heuristic used to solve MDP.

Comment: @AntoninoDG Indeed, but your problem is easier than MDP because this algorithm, which is a polynomial heuristic for the NP-complete MDP (and thus not optimal most of the time), will be optimal for your particular problem.

Comment: @PatriceGahide do you have any tips/suggestions on how to solve this problem? I'm really stuck at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. If I understand correctly you are trying to find a path with maximum distance given a budget.

Let us imagine the items here as a connected graph thus we can use tools from graph theory. The edges are the costs and the vertices or nodes are the actual items. Essentially it seems you want to find a maximum path under budget constraints so a reverse dijkstra algorithm.

Steps:

1. Select starting vertex
2. Evaluate distance from starting point.
3. Select vertex with maximum distance if this is above your budget go to the next one burning the edge that was above your budget
4. Calculate distance between the newly added item to the others as  the sum of the path to get to the item + the cost of choosing the other item (i.e. first iteration say we got item 1 then went to item 2 then the distance between item 2 and item x would be item 1 + item 2 +item x)
5. Select maximum again if above budget go to the next maximum burning the edge to the maximum that would be above your budget.
6. Repeat until budget exhausted

Hope this helps feel free to ask for clarification if this makes sense. I suggest some background reading on graph theory and associated algorithms

Comment: thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this is not the solution I was looking for! Perhaps I didn't explain the problem well. Suppose you have four Items 1,2,3,4,5.... You start from node 1 and discover that you have to move to node 2, than you should evaluate the distances d(1,2)+d(3,2) and compare this sum to d(1,4)+d(3,4) to choose between node 2 and 4 but (d(2,3) is not equal to d(1,2)+d(1,3))...